# Java - Modifying list modifies object containing list

Tags: java, list, pointers

I need to create a list of clients, each of them having a list of jobs.
when assigning a List to a client, it is passed by reference and any change made to the list ( clearing it for example ) is also reflected in the client object.

```
Client client = new Client();
Job job = new Job();
List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
client.job_run_user_login = "razvan";
job.action = "EMAIL";
jobs.add(job);
client.jobs = jobs;
jobs.clear();
```

client object before running " jobs.clear(); " line :[image]

client object before running " jobs.clear(); " line :[image]

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Are you saying you want two separate lists?  One for the client, and one that you'll modify?

Comment: `client.jobs = jobs;` makes `client.jobs` and `jobs` the same list. That doesn't make a copy. You need to copy the list of you want them to behave independently.

Comment: Why do you need to clear the list anyway? Create a new list every time you create a client, and then just leave it alone.

Comment: @AndyTurner I presented a simplified problem, my scope required me to reuse the list.

Comment: @RazvanOlariu if the accepted answer works for you, I don't see why you need to reuse the list, or even have the list in the first place. You could alternatively do `client.jobs = new ArrayList<>();`, and then do `client.jobs.add(job);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By copying a collection.

```
client.jobs = new ArrayList<>(jobs);
```

Comment: @RazvanOlariu reconsider using getters/setters and naming. `client.job_run_user_login` looks not right...

Comment: Did that, thank you!